# Задача Simple Pig Latin на Codewars

Tags: c++, строки

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что у меня в коде не так. Запускал его в CLion - всё работает, как и задумывалось. Но Codewars задание не принимает, в одном из тестов я получаю следующее сообщение:

`Caught std::exception, what(): basic_string::insert: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 4)`

Само задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать следующие манипуляции с входной строкой:

1. Переместить первую букву каждого слова строки в конец этого слова.
2. Добавить `"ay"` в конец слова.
3. Знаки препинания оставить нетронутыми.

Примеры входных и выходных данных:

```
pig_it("Pig latin is cool"); // igPay atinlay siay oolcay
pig_it("Hello world !");     // elloHay orldway !
pig_it("This is my string"); // hisTay siay ymay tringsay
```

Вот, собственно, мой код:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string pig_it(std::string str)
{
    auto numOfSpaces = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
    int wordStart = 0;
    // возвращаем индекс пробела
    int wordEnd = str.find(" ");
    for (int word = 0; word <= numOfSpaces; ++word)
    {
        if (str[wordStart] == '!' || str[wordStart] == '?' || str[wordStart] == '.' || str[wordStart] == ',')
        {
            wordStart = wordStart + 2;
            if ((numOfSpaces - word) == 1) { wordEnd = str.size(); }
            else { wordEnd = str.find(" ", wordStart); }
            continue;
        }
        str.insert(wordEnd, 1, str[wordStart]);
        str.insert(wordEnd + 1, "ay");
        str.erase(wordStart, 1);
        wordStart = wordEnd + 3;
        if ((numOfSpaces - word) == 1) { wordEnd = str.size(); }
        else { wordEnd = str.find(" ", wordStart); }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: вы не проверяете отрицательность ответа `int wordEnd = str.find(" ");`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь всё ясно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательно пройдите пошагово свой код для строки из одного слова. Например, `"Hello"`. Чтобы вам было понятнее, вставьте отладочный вывод типа

```
        continue;
    }
    std::cout << "Debug: wordEnd = " << wordEnd << std::endl;
    str.insert(wordEnd, 1, str[wordStart]);
    str.insert(wordEnd + 1, "ay");
```

и посмотрите, [*куда*](https://ideone.com/BsQ3m5) вы хотите выполнять вставку...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Разобрался =)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Прошёл последний тест в задании, после строки

`int wordEnd = str.find(" ");`

дописал следующее:

```
if (wordEnd == std::string::npos)
{
  if (str[0] == '!' || str[0] == '?' || str[0] == '.' || str[0] == ',')
  {
    return str;
  }
  str.append(1, str[0]);
  str.append("ay");
  str.erase(0, 1);
  return str;
}
```